# FindRoot equation-variable mismatch

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

I cannot figure out why `FindRoot` doesn't work and returns this error: *The number of equations does not match the number of variables in ...*

My problem: drawing ground `g`, putting a bigger circle on it.

```
g = With[{
   p = {
     {-1.088, -0.395}, {-0.572, 0.235},
     {-0.138, -0.28}, {0.404, 0.145},
     {0.854, -0.405}, {1.204, -0.07}}},
  BSplineFunction[p]]

pr = N@With[{h = 1/GoldenRatio},
   {{-1, 1}, {-h, h}}]

perp[{x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ}] := Normalize[{-y, x}]

Module[{R = .1, t = .2, p1},
 p1 = g[t] + R perp[g'[t]];
 Graphics[{
   LightGray, Rectangle @@ Transpose@pr,
   Gray, Line[g /@ Range[0, 1, .01]],
   Black, Circle[p1, R]},
  PlotRange -> pr,
  ImageSize -> 300]]
```

[image: pic1]

Now I would like to draw a smaller circle which touches the ground and the bigger circle to its left. But this produces the error:

```
FindRoot[
 EuclideanDistance[
   g[.2] + .1 perp[g'[.2]],
   g[u] + .05 perp[g'[u]]] == .1 + .05, {u, .1}]
```

Comment: I'm using a bisection routine now. I'd rather use `FindRoot` for elegance and accuracy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure [this sort of thing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037) appears in other answer, but I can't find a closely related right now.  The issue has to do with when `EuclideanDistance` and `g[u]` are evaluated.  `EuclideanDistance` is evaluated too soon, before a numeric value for `u` is passed to `g[u]`, that is, while `g[u]` still looks like a single numeric expression.  When `FindRoot` finally plugs a number in for `u`, `EuclideanDistance` has already evaluated to

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Since the `BSplineFunction`s evaluate to a vector, the whole expression becomes a vector.  Thus there are more components (2) that need to satisfy the equation than variables (1).

To fix this, one might create one's own function with a `?NumericQ` pattern test:

```
dist[u_?NumericQ] := EuclideanDistance[g[.2] + .1 perp[g'[.2]], g[u] + .05 perp[g'[u]]];

FindRoot[dist[u] - (.1 + .05), {u, .1}]
(* {u -> 0.152871} *)
```

Touching circles:

```
Module[{R = .1, r = 0.05, t = .2, p1, p2},
 p1 = g[t] + R perp[g'[t]]; 
 p2 = g[u] + r perp[g'[u]] /. FindRoot[dist[u] - (.1 + .05), {u, .1}];
 Graphics[{LightGray, Rectangle @@ Transpose @ pr, Gray, 
   Line[g /@ Range[0, 1, .01]], Black, Circle[p1, R], Circle[p2, r]}, 
  PlotRange -> pr, ImageSize -> 300]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]